# Should I edit tag wiki to add "do not use" note for tags that are candidate for burnination

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

This is an [example tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/compiler-hints/info) [compiler-hints](/questions/tagged/compiler-hints) on stackoverflow.

This tag do not suits fine since it will used on *opinion based* questions and I can not think of any question this tag can be used which is acceptable in the community.

So, should I edit tag-wiki excerpts and add "DO NOT USE IT"?

Comment: Candidate? No. Only after it was agreed to burninate add this so that future users trying to add it will see the warning. If we'll start adding "do not use" based on a single user opinion it's NOT a good idea at all.

Comment: Then how I should tag this question? As a reature-request or support?

Comment: This question here? It's a pure discussion. There is and there won't be any strict rule about this, you're looking to discuss best practices and get advice from people here. :)

Comment: I don't know what [compiler-hints] was actually being used for before it was presumably burninated, but I don't see why compiler hints as a subject should be at all subjective. I suspect if the questions were all subjective, it's because it was being used by people who don't know what hinting is. I can't find a meta question about burninating it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I was the burninator on this.  It was attached to a Delphi question where the user was getting a "hint" from the compiler that the code might have had a flaw (and with an answer saying the compiler is right).  It's a meta tag in the same way that [compiler-warnings](/questions/tagged/compiler-warnings) is a meta tag - it has different meanings to different people based on other tagging, nobody's likely to favorite it, and nobody's likely to use it as the single tag on a question.

This is the first time I've seen this tag in all the years I've been trying to clean up needless new tags in favor of existing tags that the asker didn't find.

Those of us that add the "do not use this tag" description usually add it *only in frequently recurring tags*, like [server](/questions/tagged/server) and [lib](/questions/tagged/lib).

There's also another variation, "this is the wrong tag," used for frequently recurring tags that *could* be synonyms, like [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) and [threejs](/questions/tagged/threejs).  Some people also add it to obvious typo tags, like the thousand different ways to misspeel "javascript."

Because this tag was only created once, and is unlikely to be used by anyone else within the 24 hour tag deletion window, it probably does not need the warning.

Also keep in mind that a *lot* of people ignore the tag wiki excerpt.  The "do not use" annotation only reduces actual use by a small amount.